image function does not work for sparseMatrix in R
test <- function(){
  require(Matrix);
  data(CAex, package = "Matrix");
  image(CAex)
}
test()

It draw the plot
test <- function(){
  require(Matrix);
  data(CAex, package = "Matrix");
  image(CAex);
  a<-1
}
test()

It does not draw the plot.
Why?
I use R 4.4.1 for windows and ubuntu 22.04 (WSL2)

If you don't explicitly return anything from a function, then it returns the last value evaluated. For the first, that is the image(), for the second, it is a.

Thanks. Even adding return(), test() does not draw anything as

test <- function(){require(Matrix);data(CAex, package = "Matrix");image(CAex);a<-1;return(a)}
test()
[1] 1


I wonder if it is a bug in R or Matrix packages,

You need to return the image, not a. test <- function(){require(Matrix);data(CAex, package = "Matrix");img<-image(CAex);a<-1;return(img)} >test() The image function is returning a plot using the lattice library. Those objects need to be explicitly print()-ed. Same with ggplot objects.

Thanks, but what I would like to do a bit different (I missunderstood they are same problem)

test <- function(){require(Matrix);data(CAex, package = "Matrix");jpeg(file="a.jpg");image(CAex);dev.off()}> test() This does not generate a.jpg. How can I output a.jpg?


I solved the problem.


test <- function(){require(Matrix);data(CAex, package = "Matrix");img<-jpeg(file="a.jpg");print(image(CAex));dev.off();return
(img)}


test()

works.
